# Integrate one jenkinsfile with declarative pipeline into another

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

tell me please, can I integrate one jenkinsfile with declarative pipeline into another?

The idea is to run in parallel several processes that are divided into different jenkinsfiles.

```
stage('run-parallel-branches') {
  steps {
    parallel(
      a: {
        echo "call Jenkinsfile 1"
      },
      b: {
        echo "call Jenkinsfile 2"
      }
    )
  }
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can define multiple jobs and run those jobs through a parent jenkinsFiile

Comment: you wish to run other jobs who have their respective JenkinsFile or other JenkinsFiles(which will do something else ) from one main Jenkinsfile ??

Comment: JenkinsFiles(which will do something else ) from one main Jenkinsfile

Comment: @TalhaJunaid 
The fact of the matter is that I do not want to call other Jenkins Jobs. I want to call other jenkinsfiles from one and run them  parallel. So I will not be attached to specific jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two solutions:

1. If your goal is to avoid repeating code, you can use [Shared Libraries](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) and extract the work done in `Jenkinsfile1` and `Jenkinsfile2` into a library, and then call this library instead.
2. Your two Jenkinsfile can have their dedicated jobs, and you would call them in the parallel stages (it will wait and propagate errors): `build 'myJob1'` & `build 'myJob2'`

   The problem with this approach, however, is that the invoked job will not necessarily have the same SCM commit as the parent one (if commits entered meanwhile).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think build 'myJob1' & build 'myJob2', this is what I need.